Is length of generated column affected by both @Size and @Column annotations?
Having a following property in my entity:
@Setter
@Size(min = 3, max = 255)
@Column(length = 500)
private String xo;

Generated column in h2 database is
CHARACTER VARYING(255)

I expected it to be 500. Of course I can change max/length values but shouldn't only Column annotation be taken into account when determining database column length?
Update:
I will provide class (in this case max Size is set to 400 and it will result with CHARACTER VARYING(400) on db side), properties file and pom.xml which I use.
Once the app is up and running you need to go to http://localhost:8080/h2-console insert jdbc:h2:mem:testdb url and password into form and click "Connect".
package org.example;

import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}

@Setter
@Entity
class SampleClass
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    Long id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 400)
    @Column(length = 500)
    private String xo;
}

# application.properties
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true

spring.h2.console.enabled=true

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>col_length_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>


What you are saying seems to contradict what I have read in various sources; e.g. https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-size-length-column-differences and the SpringData documentation.
